# Flexslider multilanguages

Tags: wordpress, localization, flexslider

I'm just wondering if there's a way to have the flex slider in different languages on my site. I changed the site in both Catalan and Spanish using the WPML plugin but the slider does not have an option to change. Is there any code I can put into the php for flex slider to change it to another language?